# Send HTML as Push Notification Message

Tags: notifications, push, ibm-mobilefirst

I have 2 questions:
1) I need to send HTML in Push Notification IBM MobileFirst as a message, can I achieve it? If yes, how?

2) Using MobileFirst Console, can we send Push Notification? or in case we don't have any adapter/ or data source can we acheive push notification?

glad hearing you guys soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Push notifications are meant for very short text-based messages and are limited in size; sending mark-up will in all likelihood exceed this.
2. In order to use push notifications in IBM MobileFirst, you must use adapters. Please see the user documentation and developer center for more information.